# What does a C++ vector relate to in Objective-C?

Tags: c++, objective-c, vector

I'm moving from Objective-C to C++ and am not sure what vectors are.  I've read documentation about them, I'm not quite clear though.  How would you explain C++ vectors using Objective-C analogies?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're pretty similar to `NSMutableArrays` but `vector` is a template class and so can be instanciated for any (standard-template-library compatible) type. `NSArrays` always hold `NSObjects`.

That is, assuming you mean `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1):

They're like NSMutableArrays but can hold any data type - pointer or not. However, each vector can only ever hold one type at a time. Also as it's C++ there are fewer functions e.g. no plist loading/saving.

Answer (score 1):

A C++ vector (presumably you mean something like `std::vector`) is basically an `NSArray`, except it holds any type you want (which is the template parameter, e.g. a `std::vector<int>` holds `int`s). Of course, it doesn't do memory management (which `NSArray` does), because arbitrary types aren't retain-counted. So for example a `std::vector<id>` would be rather inappropriate (assuming Obj-C++).

Comment: `std::vector` does in fact do memory management for you (that's the whole point of `std::vector`). I think what you meant is that things like `std::vector<int*>` does not call `delete` on each `int*` elements, nor does any reference counting of its elements. Smart pointers can be used to add reference counting support e.g. `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>>`.

Comment: @Insilico: In Obj-C terms, "memory management" means reference-counting of Obj-C objects.

Answer (score 1):

NSArray is a wrapper around CFArray. CFArray can store any data type.

I don't know much about C++, but it sounds like CFArray can do everything you'd use a vector for? When creating a CFArray you give it a CFArrayCallBacks pointer, which contains any logic that is specific to the data type being stored.

Of course, you could always just rename your Obj-C file to *.mm, and mix C++ into your objective-c.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFOundation/Reference/CFArrayRef/Reference/reference.html

Comment: I think you got it backwards.  I know Objective-C, and I'm learning C++.

Comment: Oh, you're right I did get it backwards. Still, AFAIK a vector is the same as a CFArray, not really the same as an NSArray.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ an Array is basically just a pointer to a contiguous block of data---a series of elements.  It offers no built-in methods, or higher functionality.

```
int intArr[] = {0,1,2,3};
```

is the same as

```
int *intArr = (int *)malloc(4*sizeof(int));
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { intArr[i] = i; }
```

A vector (std::vector), on the other hand, is a container for elements (basically like an array) which also offers additional built in methods (see: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/) such as

```
vector<int> intArr;
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { intArr.push_back(i); }
// this yields the same content; i.e. intArr = {0,1,2,3}
```

Both arrays and vectors can be used on any type of objects, int, double, 'MySpacePirateWizardClass' etc.  The big bonus of vectors is the additional functionality from built-in functions like:

```
int arrSize = intArr.size();  // vector also includes useful information
int *firstElement = intArr.begin();    // methods for creating pointers to elements
intArr.delete(0);             // modify elements
intArr.insert(0, 2);          // modify vector
// now: intArr = {2,1,2,3}
```

etc etc.

When I know I'm not going to be short on space (or looking at massive amounts of data), I always use vectors because they're so more convenient (even just the size() method alone is reason enough).

Answer (score -1):

Think about vectors as advanced arrays.

If you are new to C++, this page will be your best friend:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/